# Marginalising out two variables from an expectation

Tags: expected-value, marginal-distribution

Lets say I have the following expected value:
$$E[Y|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3]$$

and I want to marginalize out the *continuous* random variables $X_2$ and $X_3$ to arrive at:
$$E[Y|X_1=x_1]$$

How can I write down the integral to get from the first quantity to the second? We can assume that $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent (does this make a difference?).

Marginalizing out a single variable is simple enough, but I'm not sure of the proper notation for the two variable case. My integral calculus is generally very rusty so it would be much appreciated if you were able to spell out your steps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short**: The [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) (LoTE) states $E[E[X|A]]=E[X]$. That is, your solution is $$E[Y|X_1=x_1]=\int{\int{E[Y|X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, X_3=x_3]dx_2}dx_3}$$

---

**Long**: the term $E[Y|X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, X_3=x_3]$ is conditional on specific values of $x_1,x_2,x_3$. In order to obtain the marginal probability/expectation of some term, we need to sum/integrate over all values of the other variables. It seems from your answer that you're not fully familiar with the reason for that. When we condition $A|X$, we kinda "freezing" $X$ and looking at the changes to $A$. But, and this is important, in the real world $X$ is not frozen and we need to address the possible changes to it. This is where we meet the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) (LoTP), which says $P(A)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(A|X=x)f_X(x)dx$. That is, we sum over all possible values of $X$ to get the marginal probability of $A$. Now, if we recall the definition of expected value $E[A]=\int a\cdot P(A=a) da$ and conditional expectation $E[A|X=x]=\int{a\cdot P(A|X=x)}da$, we get that LoTE is just an application of LoTP:

$$E[A]=\int{a\cdot\left(\int{P(A|X=x)f_X(x)}dx\right)} da=\\ \int{\int{\left(a\cdot P(A|X=x)f_X(x)\right)}da} dx=\\ \int{E[A|X=x]f_X(x)} dx$$

as in your case we're would like to get the marginal expectation without $X_2,X_3$, the solution would be
$$E[Y|X_1=x_1]=\int{\int{E[Y|X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, X_3=x_3]f_{X_2,X_3}(x_2,x_3)dx_2}dx_3}$$

where $f_{X_2,X_3}$ is the joint distribution of $X_2,X_3$. If they are independent, this simplifies to
$$E[Y|X_1=x_1]=\int{\int{E[Y|X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, X_3=x_3]f_{X_2}(x_2)f_{X_3}(x_3)dx_2}dx_3}$$

Comment: Thanks! I knew that LoTE was the solution here, I just didn't know how to put it into practice. Typically the solutions I've seen include the PDF of the variable(s) being marginalised on the RHS (multiplied with the conditional expectation). I note that's missing in your solution. Is that implicit in your presentation/deliberately excluded/something else?

Comment: Indeed, it is implicit

Comment: One last question so I'm 100% with it. I imagine that we would integrate over the *joint* pdf of X2 and X3 in general, but that, when X2 and X3 are independent, we could instead integrate over the product of the marginal pdf's of X2 and X3?

Comment: If $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are all independent then sure - you integrate over the product of PDFs (that is, integrate them one at a time).

Comment: All the "equations" you displayed here missed some essential parts (i.e., probability measures of the conditioning random variable(s)).  For example, the law of total probability is not $P(A) = \int P(A|X = x)dx$, but $P(A) = \int P(A|X = x)f_X(x)dx$.  See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601921/formula-of-conditional-probability-when-we-have-discrete-and-continuous-random-v/602071#602071) for more technical details.

Comment: Yeah as I commented the PDFs are implicit here, the full notation definitely includes them as well.

Comment: @Spätzle Maybe it would be better for the clarity and usefulness of your answer, to write the mathematical expressions explicitly.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I added the PDFs here

Comment: Your solution is not true in general, but only under a specific assumption as regards the statistical relation between the three conditioning variables. In case you 're interested, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f$ denote any density, characterized by its arguments. Let $f(y \mid \{x_1, x_2, x_3\})$ be the conditional density of $Y$ given $X_1, X_2, X_3$. Then we have (limits of integration formally are $(-\infty, \infty)$ and are omitted, with the understanding that the densities may be set to zero over a subset of the extended reals).

$$E[Y|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3] = \int y\cdot f(y\mid\{x_1,x_2, x_3\}) ~dy \tag{1}$$

By Bayes theorem for densities (or the "chain rule")

$$f\left(y \mid \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}\right) = \frac{f(y, x_1, x_2, x_3)}{f(x_1, x_2, x_3)} \tag{2}$$

Inserting $(2)$ into $(1)$ ,

$$E[Y|X_1=x_1,X_2=x_2,X_3=x_3] = \int y\cdot \frac{f(y, x_1, x_2, x_3)}{f(x_1, x_2, x_3)}~ dy \tag{3}$$

**Implementing [the suggestion of user @Spätzle](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/629970/28746)**, we would then have

$$E[Y|X_1=x_1] = \iiint y\cdot \frac{f(y, x_1, x_2, x_3)}{f(x_1, x_2, x_3)}f(x_2,x_3)~dy\, dx_2\,dx_3. \tag{4}$$

Applying the chain rule
$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f(x_1 \mid \{x_2, x_3\})f(x_2,x_3)$$

and inserting this into $(4)$ and simplifying, we get

$$E[Y|X_1=x_1] = \iiint y\cdot \frac{f(y, x_1, x_2, x_3)}{f(x_1 \mid \{x_2, x_3\})}~dy\, dx_2\,dx_3. \tag{5}$$

**But is it so? Let's verify.**

What we are after is, again applying the chain rule

$$E[Y|X_1=x_1] = \int y\cdot f(y \mid x_1)~ dy = \int y\cdot \frac{f(y , x_1 )}{f(x_1)}dy = \frac{\int y\cdot f(y , x_1 )~dy}{f(x_1)}\tag{6}.$$

We have
$$f(y , x_1 ) = \iint f(y , x_1 , x_2, x_3)~dx_2\,dx_3, \tag{7}$$

and inserting this into $(6)$ we get

$$E[Y|X_1=x_1] =  \frac{\iiint yf(y , x_1 , x_2, x_3)~dy\,dx_2\,dx_3}{f(x_1)}\tag{8}.$$

**Q: When is eq. $(5)$ the same as eq.$(8)$?**

**A: Only when $X_1$ is independent from $(X_2, X_3)$ in which case $f(x_1 \mid \{x_2, x_3\}) = f(x_1).$**

So the suggestion by user @Spätzle is not true in general. The reason why? We do not marginalize out all conditioning variables, we keep one, so we must take into account the possible dependence between it and the other two. This is why the invocation of the Law of Total Probability / Expectation fails here.

Finally, using analogous manipulations as before, from $(8)$ we arrive at the generally valid expression

$$E[Y|X_1=x_1] =  \iint E(Y\mid X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, X_3=x_3) f(x_2, x_3 \mid x_1)\,dx_2\,dx_3.\tag{9}$$

Verbally: we should not "average over" $X_2$ and $X_3$ by using their joint density, but by using their joint density *conditional* on $X_1=x_1$.